# Input checkbox always returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div id='foo'>
    <input type='checkbox' value='english' name='bar[english]' />
    <input type='checkbox' value='spanish' name='bar[spanish]' />

    <button type='button' class='button'>Me!</button>
</div>​
```

**JavaScript** (jQuery)

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    status = '';
    $('#foo input[name*="bar"]').each(function() {
        status += $(this).val() + ': ' + $(this).is('checked') + ".\n";
    });
    alert(status);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pCmXJ/

You know tell me why the two checkbox always return false? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably because you want the [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/):

```
$(this).is(":checked") // <-- Note the colon (:) before "checked"
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/nht6w/

Answer (score 2):

Or this :

```
$(this).attr("checked")
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `$(this).is(':checked')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `:checked` selector not `checked`

```
status += $(this).val() + ': ' + $(this).is(':checked') + ".\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are checking if the `input` element is a `checked` element, which it of course not is as it's an `input` element (and there are no `checked` elements). Use the [`:checked` pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/):

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```